# How to forecast with new dataset by "MarkovAutoregression" model in Statsmodels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels, forecasting, markov

I'd like to fit a MarkovAutoregression model with training time-seriese dataset(train_data) and make it forecast with validation time-seriese dataset(val_data). Training part is like below and I don't find any errors.

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression import MarkovAutoregression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Generate some random data
np.random.seed(0)
n_samples = 100
data = np.random.randn(n_samples)

# Split data into training and validation datasets
train_data, val_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Fit the Markov autoregression model
lag_order = 2  # Order of the autoregressive process
model = MarkovAutoregression(train_data, k_regimes=2, order=lag_order)
result = model.fit()
```

Then, prediction part has to be like below according to a [official site](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression.MarkovAutoregression.predict.html) about predict() method.

```
MarkovAutoregression.predict(
    params, 
    start=None, 
    end=None, 
    probabilities=None, 
    conditional=False
)
```

As you can see, there is arguments of **start** and **end** in order to designate target time window by indexs. Are these indexs for **train_data** which has already used in fit()? How can I pass my **val_data** to predict() from the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

From my farther investigation, questioned forecasting function in markov_autoregression is not implemented yet.
See link below,
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5537